# PhP Using echo to print out multiple variables with ),(,: in between

Tags: php, variables, syntax, echo

I've been looking everywhere about text formatting with echo but I couldn't find a simple answer on how do I echo my variables like this: **field1(field2,field3,field4): field5.** Without using $row['field'], or maybe it would be even easier that way?
Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind, turns out you can use echo "-$field1($field2, $field3, $field4): $field5"; Didn't know you can freely use these symbols in between $field's, thanks for the downvotes though.

Comment: Don't complain about the downvotes, your question is just not clear. Next time follow those simple guidelines: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. Are you trying to echo an array  ?
If so check the print_r function (http://www.php.net/print_r‎).

```
print_r($your_array_here)
```

Or you are trying to join the variables ? (http://www.php.net/implode)

```
echo implode(',', array($variable1, $variable2, $variable3));
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is a way to do this (if you are really talking about data right from the DB) as you will always have an array and you have to access that array. Post what is it you are trying to achieve, perhaps there is a faster way.